# How do you save checkbox settings with function in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, checkbox, properties

I'm trying to create an application with a settings dialog. Inside the dialog, there will be a checkbox. I went to the settings panel in visual studio and made a name to the setting as "AutoEnable". I set the type to bool, and scope to user. I've also set the value to true. Meanwhile in the form, I've set a Checkbox1_CheckedChanged function to the checkbox and added the function as following:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            MainEditor m = new MainEditor();
            m.menustrip1.Visible = true;
        }
        if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
        {
            MainEditor m = new MainEditor();
            m.menustrip1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

When i tested it out, the checkbox was set to checked as the value I've set before. I unchecked the checkbox and close the dialog then open it up again. The result was fine...it was unchecked like i did. But the one problem i find is when i unchecked the checkbox and closed the dialog and when back to the MainEditor, the code function from checkbox1 was not working. What did i made wrong? Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are initializing the MainEditor to a new instance instead of calling the OpenForms. Try this:

```
var m = Application.OpenForms.OfType<MainEditor>().SingleOrDefault();
if (m != null)
{
  m.menustrip1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. giving you a vote for that.